# How to replace default KAHA DB with Oracle database in ActiveMQ-5.11

Tags: apache, activemq-classic

We are started using Apache ActiveMQ with default Kaha Database.

Now we are going to use it very effectively to reduce the risk of data loss we wish to replace the default database with Orcale database.How we can do it I tried to change actvemq.xml

```
    <bean id="Orcale-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:*.*.*.*:1521/xe"/>
      <property name="username" value="username"/>
      <property name="password" value="password"/>
      <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>
     </bean>
Below  one is adapter configuration

     <persistenceAdapter>
          <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="Orcale-ds"/>
       </persistenceAdapter>
```

But server is not starting  so how to configure oracle database with activeMQ.
Error's in log file is below

```
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.11.1]
2015-11-18 16:58:30,251 | ERROR | Failed to load: class path resource [activemq.xml], reason: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#141e366' of type [org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter] while setting bean property 'persistenceAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#141e366' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory | main
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#141e366' of type [org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter] while setting bean property 'persistenceAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#141e366' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:287)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)[spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
```

The error starting with some conversation.

```
ERROR | Failed to load: class path resource [activemq.xml], reason: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0' 
defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#dca1b0' of type [org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter] 
while setting bean property 'persistenceAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'(inner bean)#dca1b0' defined in class path resource [activemq.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: 
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'javax.sql.DataSource' for property 'dataSource'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [javax.sql.DataSource] for property 'dataSource': no matching editors or conversion strategy found | 
org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory | main
```

Comment: You'll get more help if you report errors from broker logs etc, otherwise people have nothing to go on

Comment: Yes, please do add the error logs. Did you remember to add the driver in [activemq_home]/lib/optional ?

Comment: Yes I added jdbc7 in lib optional ,Still facing issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to add bean (with #) not string as -

```
<jdbcPersistenceAdapter  dataSource="#Orcale-ds"/>
```

It is treating datasrouce as String than a datasource bean